# Unable to resolve compiling error for .Net 4.0 website

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I'm currently getting a compiling error when I try to access a page of my website. This error has only started happening. It's in the compiling code for a page that's having data bound to it. A snippet of the error is as follows:

```
 error BC30456: 'Eval' is not a member of 'ASP.main_decision_aspx'.

 dataBindingExpressionBuilderTarget.Text = Global.System.Convert.ToString(Me.Eval("Fullname"), Global.System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

I'm not sure how to go about resolving this as it's not something I'm able to access and modify manually. the weird thing is that it only occurs on this one page of the website. Other pages with identical functionality aren't affected. I've checked the version of .net in IIS and compared that to the one in the web.config and they both match. I'm at a bit of a loss with how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We managed to find a solution so I'm going to respond to myself just in case someone else has the same problem and is looking for a fix.

We created a new page and started copying the code from the page across. We would publish the website after we added some code and tested that we could browse to the page, which we could. Eventually we had all the code in the new page and it was working fine. Problem solved!

Out of interest we renamed the new page to the old one and tried to access the page and we got the same error again. On changing the name back it worked fine.

TLDR version

1. Create a new page with a different name, copy your code across.
2. Try renaming the page.